# JavaCC generates code that fails while parsing UTF-8 strings

Tags: java, utf-8, javacc

I have an older project, where a JavaCC grammar was used to generate classes to parse a custom language.

Now, several years later I have to adapt the grammar to add functionality (just a minor change).
This works, but when running all tests, I see I have a problem parsing UTF-8 characters.
I don't really have an idea what is causing this.
I reverted my change to the grammar and recreated the classes, but the problem remains.
As soon as I run javacc with the grammar and run my tests, the one with the UTF-8 characters fail.

This is the call I am using:

```
java -cp javacc-7.0.10.jar javacc -GRAMMAR_ENCODING=UTF-8 functionsGrammar.jj
```

I tried it with all major javacc versions from 4.x to 7.0.10, they all have the same problem.
I also tried this with different java version (6, 7, 8, 11) but that also did not make any difference.

Below you can find the relevant parts of the grammar:

```
options
{
  JDK_VERSION = "1.6";

  LOOKAHEAD= 2;
  FORCE_LA_CHECK = true;

  static = false;
}

TOKEN:
{
...
|< STRING : < QUOTES > (~["\"", "\\"])* ("\\"~[] (~["\"", "\\"])*)* < QUOTES > >
...}

TOKEN:
{
...
| < LIST :
    < LCURLY_BRACE > < SPACES >
    ( < STRING > | < DATE > | < PARAMETER_FIELD_ID > | < PARAMETER_ELEMENT > | < NULL > )
    ( < COMMA > < SPACES >
      ( < STRING > | < DATE > | < PARAMETER_FIELD_ID > | < PARAMETER_ELEMENT > | < NULL > )
    )*
...}
```

It fails for the string: "美丽的树" but works when changed to "slkdfj" for example.

I wonder if there are any options for JavaCC that I am missing? Or other java / javacc version combinations that might work?

Comment: Are you certain it supports Unicode?

Comment: @g00se It does, until I regenerate everything with JavaCC

Comment: I'm talking about JavaCC *itself*

Comment: Perhaps consider trying [JavaCC 21](https://javacc.com/) instead: _"JavaCC 21 is a continuation of development on the JavaCC codebase that was open-sourced by Sun Microsystems in mid 2003. **It is currently the most advanced version of JavaCC**."_ Also see [JavaCC 21 Now Supports Full Unicode!](https://javacc.com/2021/03/29/javacc-21-now-supports-full-unicode/) And if possible, use a more recent JDK. **JavaCC 21** supports the use of JDK 17. Apart from any potential JavaCC problems arising from using a very old (and unsupported) JDK such as 1.6, it may introduce security issues.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the actual problem you face? Just stating _"I have a problem"_ and _"It fails"_ is a bit vague. Are there any error messages or stack traces, or do you just see your tests fail, with no additional details? It looks like there are [debug options available](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/tutorials/examples.html).

Comment: JavaCC certainly supports Unicode.  Have you tried using the `UNICODE_INPUT=true` option?  If the input is from a file, you need to ensure that the file `Reader` decodes the files to unicode code-points correctly.  E.g., by specifying "UTF-8" as the file's encoding.  See the FAQ https://javacc.github.io/javacc/faq.html#question-3.21 for more information.

Comment: I should add that I'm not sure that JavaCC will support unicode beyond plane 0.

Comment: Te `-GRAMMAR_ENCODING=UTF-8` is not helpful, since that is telling JavaCC how to read its input.  It does not tell the generated parser how to read it's input.  Again, the place to do that is where you create the `Reader` object.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell JavaCC does now support [Unicode beyond the BMP](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/): _"The lexical analyzer of JavaCC can handle full Unicode input, and lexical specifications may also include any Unicode character"_. (Or did you mean something else?)

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Thanks, that got me in the right direction. Using UNICODE_INPUT = true and JAVA_UNICODE_ESCAPE = true enabled me to use UTF-8 characters for parsing strings.

Comment: So it looks like the answer to my initial question is: "not automatically"

Comment: As far as I can see, your grammar only contains ASCII characters. Your problem could be in the way you instanciate your parser class. Are you using the constructor with an encoding parameter? `new Parser(inputStream, "UTF-8")`?

Answer (score 0):

Legacy JavaCC most certainly does not support the full, current Unicode standard, i.e. 32-bit characters. This is explained [here](https://parsers.org/javacc21/javacc-21-now-supports-full-unicode/). Granted, it may well be that the OP does not (at least currently) need more than the 16-bit (BMP, basic multilingual plane) characters. However, JavaCC 21 supports full Unicode. Besides that, JavaCC 21 fixes a plethora of existing bugs in legacy JavaCC that have not been addressed in over 20 years. I think that [this article](https://parsers.org/rants-non-technical/a-bugs-life/) is illuminating in that regard.